# onUserLeaveHint() is [sometimes] called with startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-picture-in-picture

I'm implementing PiP in our Android app. It's a navigation app that it's main activity is a full screen map. When minimized (with home button for example) it's going correctly to PiP mode through onUserLeaveHint().
The problem is that the main activity has some functions that open secondary activities and sometimes the app goes also to PiP mode.

What I'm doing wrong or what I have to change to be sure that the app only goes to PiP when app is "minimized"?

Here are some code, but I think there's nothing special.

This is to go to PiP mode:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    if (iWantToBeInPipModeNow()) { //internal logic to allow PiP
        PictureInPictureParams params = new PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                        .setAspectRatio(new Rational(9, 16))
                        .build();
        enterPictureInPictureMode(params);
    }
}
```

This is to open the secondary activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == myButton) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SomeActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_SELECT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than use `onUserLeaveHint()`, perhaps use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`. Or, perhaps replace the secondary activities with fragments.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I tried it, but unfortunately this is not an option. ProcessLifecycleOwner (ON_STOP) works, but is too slow, the effect of the app being "minimized" is lost. It disappears and half a second later appears the PiP. Using fragments is not an option neither, because one of this secondary activities is the external camera app, so is not in our control.

Comment: "because one of this secondary activities is the external camera app" -- I suspect that is where your problem lies. The user is leaving your app, so `onUserLeaveHint()` might get called. You will need to have flags or in your activity that indicates when the user is leaving based on your actions (so you do not show PiP mode in those cases).

Answer (score 1):

`onUserLeaveHint()` is not a reliable Android lifecycle callback to detect "Home" button clicks. Even though the official documentation specifies that you can use it to detect "when the user presses the Home key", I have found this to be false.

For example, `onUserLeaveHint()` might be called when the an Android native dialog is prompted, or when you start another Activity.
I have also found that when Gesture Navigation is enabled (Android 11 and above) and the user goes to "Recents" and then exists app - `onUserLeaveHint()` will not be called.

Unfortunately, until this day I have not found any air-tight way to detect "Home" button clicks in Android. I guess that OS designers do not want app developers to detect this easily.